# Where is Blender version 2.79?

Tags: modeling, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, add-on

i tried finding Blender 2.79, but only found 2.79b in the official Blender website. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 4):

Main page of blender.org only shows the latest stable release.

For the previous versions of 2.79 check out this link http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/

You can find more previous versions here

http://download.blender.org/release/